# What is the difference between this two Scala definitions

Tags: scala

I have the below 2 definitions in Scala, Which gives me the same result. But It's bit different from each other.

```
def sum(f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int =
if (a > b) 0 else f(a) + sum(f)(a + 1, b)     //> sum: (f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int)Int

sum(x => x*x)(1,2)   //> res3: Int = 5
```

The second one is

```
def sum(f: Int => Int,a: Int, b: Int): Int =
if (a > b) 0 else f(a) + sum(f,a + 1, b)      //> sum2: (f: Int => Int, a: Int, b: Int)Int

sum(x => x*x,1,2)                               //> res4: Int = 5
```

The only different I see is `sum(f: Int => Int,a: Int, b: Int)` and `sum(f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int)` . In the latter case the function parameter and the values parameters are separated.

What is this behavior. Is this really a same or is there a different between them ?

Comment: this might help.http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/function-currying-in-scala

Answer (score 6):

With respect to the way that you're using them they are pretty much identical. But the first version has some additional flexibility (and utility) in general.

For example

```
val g = sum(x => x*x) _  //g has type (Int, Int) => Int
println(g(2, 3))         //prints 13
```

This is called currying. You can do this with more than two argument lists, e.g.

```
def foo(b: Boolean)(i: Int)(s: String)(d: Double): Int = ...
val g = foo(true) _  //g has type Int => (String => (Double => Int))
val h = g(3) _       //h has type String => (Double => Int)
val r = h("asdf") _  //r has type Double => Int
```

The underscore can sometimes be left off depending on the context, e.g.

```
val r: Int => Double = foo(true)(3)("asdf")
```

Multiple argument lists are also used for implicit parameters, as well as at times when the Scala compiler needs some help with the type inferencing. When used together with call-by-name parameters they can also be handy for creating fake syntax or control structures via libraries, e.g.

```
def repeat(n: Int)(body: => Unit) { 
  var i = n
  while (i > 0) { i -= 1; body }
}

var counter = 0
repeat(10) {                  //This method call (repeat) looks a bit like a part                   
  println(s"Hello: $counter") //of the language due to call-by-name argument, 
  counter += 1                //multiple parameter lists, use of curly braces, etc.
}
```

results in

Hello: 1
Hello: 2
.
.
.
Hello 9

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are the same. You can use multiple parameter blocks for several reasons, none of which apply here:

1. To help type inference with generic methods (e.g. if you have `def foo[A](a: A, f: A => A)` and call `foo(1, _ + 1)` you might expect the compiler to understand that `A` is `Int`. But it can't do that before determining the type of `_ + 1`. If you use `def foo[A](a: A)(f: A => A)` instead, it'll work.
2. To use previous arguments in default values. E.g. `def foo(x: Int, y: Int = x)` doesn't compile, `def foo(x: Int)(y: Int = x)` does.
3. A function argument by itself can be written in braces without parentheses:

   ```
   def sum(a: Int, b: Int)(f: Int => Int): Int

   sum(1, 2) { x => x*x }
   ```
4. The last block can contain [implicit parameters](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-parameters.html).